# Keep getting a "Fatal error" when trying to upload an image

Tags: error

When I go to upload a new image from my computer I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\finfo_open() in /home/cre8sub/public_html/westleigh/system/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php on line 117
```

Is there something I need to change in the MimeType.php file? or is there another problem? or is it because I am on the free version?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you enable the extension = fileinfo.so in your php.ini settings. Secondly the image type might not be listed in the system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php. Refer to https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/fileinfo-in-2-10-0 for further explanations